# Python: Filter data from mongodb based on name: something}

Tags: python, database, mongodb

So I have the following data in my **mongodb**:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b479eca54159200044ca729"
    },
    "name": "note1",
    "content": 118
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b479eca54159200044ca729"
    },
    "name": "note2",
    "content": 122
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b479eca54159200044ca729"
    },
    "name": "note3",
    "content": 920
}
```

How do I get the content for the note3 for example? Or if an user wants to get the note2 content?

So, to explain it better:

If I type in console note2 I should get 122 and if I type note3 I should get 920 as output.

Comment: Just need to clarify, are you using python api or mongo shell to query?

Comment: I'm using pymongo so it's python api

Comment: OK, cool. I will post an answer below. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# I made an assumption your db and collection were called 'test'
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
collection = db.test

find = "note1"

curs = collection.find({"name":find}, {"content":True, "_id":False})

for item in curs:
  print(item)
```

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?